# Outlook 2013 deleted messages show in Gmail inbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

I am using GMail with Outlook 2013, configured as IMAP. When I select and delete multiple messages from Outlook, they are removed from the inbox and are moved to Trash. After, I do "Empty Folder" on the Gmail\Trash folder and switch folders multiple times, GMail (web interface) still shows some of those deleted messages in the GMail inbox.

My settings are:
GMail: Auto-Expunge on.

Outlook: Default IMAP settings (I have not modified adjusted any settings).

The goal is to have the Inbox in Outlook and the GMail Inbox be consistent and in-sync. Considering the purpose of IMAP, this should be the default behavior.

What is going on? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How long are you waiting between checking?  I know if I delete something from my phone, it takes a few minutes before the web reflects the change, and vice versa.

Comment: I have tried various time periods. From checking immediately to waiting till the next day.

Comment: I see the same behavior. I'll delete messages in Outlook 2013, but they'll remain in my inbox on gmail.com and other devices (all using IMAP).

Answer (score 3):

I finally found an acceptable way to deal with this Gmail/Outlook 2013 issue.

1. Go into your Gmail settings at gmail.com. Under *When I mark a message in IMAP as deleted* set Auto-Expunge to *off*. Then set *When a message is marked as deleted...* to *Move the message to the Trash* (or something else, if you prefer). Click *Save Changes*.
   [image: Gmail Settings]
2. In Outlook 2013, click on your Gmail inbox. Then, at the very top of Outlook, click on Folder. You'll see *Purge* in the toolbar area in the middle. Click *Purge* then click *Purge Options*. Select the *Advanced* tab. Uncheck both checkboxes under *Delete Items*. Click *Ok*. *(Note that checking the option "Purge items when switching folders while online" doesn't seem to have any effect with this setup.)*
   [image: Outlook 2013 Settings]
3. Now when you receive and then delete a new email in Outlook, Gmail will put that email in your Trash folder. Gmail also gives that email the Trash tag, *but it does not remove the Inbox tag*.

This isn't 100% ideal, as the Inbox tag remains on the email. However, since it does receive the Trash tag and ends up in your trash (and does not appear in your Inbox nor in All Mail) this is acceptable to me. Gmail deletes all items in the Trash folder when those items are 30 days old. I also cross checked this with my phone (an iPhone). From what I can tell, everything behaves as I would expect.

Answer (score 3):

1. **DELETING** the messages in Outlook 2013 (hitting delete or clicking the big "**X**" on the `Outlook Ribbon`) will then move them to the **`[GMAIL] > TRASH`** folder:

   [image]
2. then you can **PERMANENTLY DELETE** them from the **`[GMAIL] > TRASH`** in Outlook **AND** in GMail, by clicking **`PURGE > TRASH FOLDER`** from the `Outlook Ribbon`
3. Make sure that your **GMail IMAP settings** look like this (**`Folder Size Limits`** can be whatever you'd like):
   [image]
4. Make sure your **Outlook IMAP settings** look like this:

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Outlook marks files ready for deletion on the IMAP server but they're only deleted once the purge command is sent. I'm guessing sometimes you close Outlook after you've deleted the files and before the purge command is sent and then the intent to send the purge command is lost.

I found [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-za/outlook-help/purge-imap-items-marked-for-deletion-HP010080420.aspx) information from Microsoft.

Comment: thank you for your answer. However, the using the purge method, mentioned in the link, does not remedy the situation. It still behaves the same way.